# Can I use the MIDI In of the Launchpad Pro to send MIDI messages to my computer?

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard

*I'm not sure whether this is on topic here. Please direct me elsewhere if it isn't.*

I wonder about the MIDI In port of the Launchpad Pro.  From Ableton you can send MIDI messages to the Launchpad, specifically notes to light up the pads.

I wonder if this is also the *only* use of the MIDI In port.

What I want to do is built a Arduino-based MIDI controller that I can use with my Launchpad. It is supposed to send MIDI messages like Pitch Bend, Modulation or Sustain Pedal.

My question is:

> If I send MIDI controller messages to the MIDI In port of the
>   Launchpad would they be send to my computer / Ableton?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look it you can 'forward' midi messages from your Arduino to your computer via launchpad pro.  [Looks like you can only send sysex messages to light pad / scroll text ect](https://d19ulaff0trnck.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/novation/downloads/10598/launchpad-pro-programmers-reference-guide_0.pdf)

Can you perhaps multiplex the message to both your computer and the launchpad?

Comment: Well,  it isn't completely clear to me from the document, but you are *probably* right. - I don't actually need to send any messages to the Launchpad, that's why I'm going to build my MIDI controller as a standalone USB device now.